# Gerar uma unica página com todos os registro

Tags: c#, lista, view

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna uma lista com objetos. Dessa lista, eu percorro cada posição, defino alguns parâmetros do objetos e retorno para uma *view*.

O que estou tentando fazer é:

Percorrer todas posições dessa lista e gerar uma unica *view*. Porém, o acontece é que quando executo o método, minha view só carrega o primeiro objeto da lista.

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string cnpj, int numero, string chave)
     {
         var notaDb = await DbContext.GetNotaAsync(cnpj, numero, chave);

         var notas = DbContext.ObterTodasNotas(notaDb.Prestador.Id);

         var items = new List<NotaFiscalViewModel>();

         if (notaDb == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }

         foreach (var nota_ in notas)
         {
              var nota = await GetNotaAsync(nota_);
             var cidade = await DbContext.GetMunicipioNomeAsync(notaDb.CodigoTributacaoMunicipio);
             nota.CodigoTributacaoMunicipio = cidade.Descricao + " - " + cidade.Estado.UF;

             var prefeitura = await DbContext.GetPrefeituraAsync();
             nota.Imagem = prefeitura.Imagem;
             nota.Prefeitura = await ContribuinteController.GetContribuinteViewModelAsync(prefeitura);
             var cnpjPrefeitura = await DbContext.GetConfiguracaoAsync();
             nota.Prefeitura.CpfCnpj = cnpjPrefeitura.CnpjPrefeitura;

             return Ok<NotaFiscalViewModel>(nota);
         }
         return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que deseje retornar a lista de todas notas alteras, sendo assim, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string cnpj, int numero, string chave)
{
     var notaDb = await DbContext.GetNotaAsync(cnpj, numero, chave);

     var notas = DbContext.ObterTodasNotas(notaDb.Prestador.Id);

     var items = new List<NotaFiscalViewModel>();

     if (notaDb == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     //Lista de notas
     List<NotaFiscalViewModel> viewModels = new List<NotaFiscalViewModel>();

     foreach (var nota_ in notas)
     {
          var nota = await GetNotaAsync(nota_);
         var cidade = await DbContext.GetMunicipioNomeAsync(notaDb.CodigoTributacaoMunicipio);
         nota.CodigoTributacaoMunicipio = cidade.Descricao + " - " + cidade.Estado.UF;

         var prefeitura = await DbContext.GetPrefeituraAsync();
         nota.Imagem = prefeitura.Imagem;
         nota.Prefeitura = await ContribuinteController.GetContribuinteViewModelAsync(prefeitura);
         var cnpjPrefeitura = await DbContext.GetConfiguracaoAsync();
         nota.Prefeitura.CpfCnpj = cnpjPrefeitura.CnpjPrefeitura;

        //Adiciona notas na lista
         viewModels.Add(nota);             
     }
     //Retorna todas notas com as cinfigurações efetuadas
     return Ok<List<NotaFiscalViewModel>>(viewModels);
}
```

Comment: Opa, cheguei a corrigir isso. Porém, ele só retorna o ultimo item da lista.

Comment: E pra vc passar 'nota' fora do foreach, precisa declara-lo antes. Dessa forma que está seu método jamais vai compilar.

Comment: @ViniciusMatos verdade, não prestei atenção nisso; você deseja retornar a lista de notas?